# Why the file '/sys/power/state' in Android is always 'mem'?

Tags: android, linux, power-management

In my opinion, the `/sys/power/state` file should be `ON` when system wakes up, and be `mem` when the system sleeps. But when I use `adb shell cat /sys/power/state` command to check the file contents, it is always `mem`, even when the system is awake.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading this file gives the list of possible states.

You wouldn't be able to read the file if the system was sleeping anyway. :)